# Finding the Integer solution to $a^3+b^2+c^2=2013$

Tags: number-theory

this is my first time posting and I hope someone can help because this question has been driving me crazy... For a bit of background I am a sophomore math major in college, I have taken math up through vector calculus and Differential equations - I came across this problem during the AMATYC Student Math League exam.

The equation $a^3 + b^2 + c^2 = 2013$ has a solution in positive integers for which $b$ is a
multiple of $5$; find $a, b$, and $c$.

Finding any solution is trivial, but I am not familiar with how to find an integer solution.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$  2013 - 10^3 = 1013  $$ is prime and
$$ 1013 \equiv 1 \pmod 4.  $$

There is guaranteed to be an expression, and
$$ 1013 = 22^2 + 23^2.  $$

So
$$   10^3 + 22^2 + 23^2 = 2013.     $$
The other solutions are
$$   2^3 + 22^2 + 39^2 = 2013,     $$
$$   2^3 + 18^2 + 41^2 = 2013,     $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  4^3 + 10^2 + 43^2 = 2013. }    $$

Evidently that is the one they want, $(4,10,43).$
Meanwhile, there are 434 known positive integers that have no such expression, the largest being 5,042,631. However, if we do not restrict the sign of your $a,$ every integer $n$ has an expression as $$ n = a^3 + b^2 + c^2, $$ and there is an explicit recipe for finding an expression, which generally produces $a < 0.$ For example
  $$  16028054332129464515^2 + 6357026807909^2 - 6357024286595^3 = 5042631  $$

Note that, for $n \geq 0,$ we find $5042631 - n^3$ is never the sum of two squares, as (if positive) it is always divisible by some prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ but not divisible by $q^2.$

---

```
5042631 - 0^3  =   5042631 - 0  =  5042631 = 3 * 11 * 41 * 3727
5042631 - 1^3  =   5042631 - 1  =  5042630 = 2 * 5 * 47 * 10729
5042631 - 2^3  =   5042631 - 8  =  5042623 = 1109 * 4547
5042631 - 3^3  =   5042631 - 27  =  5042604 = 2^2 * 3 * 7 * 173 * 347
5042631 - 4^3  =   5042631 - 64  =  5042567 = 43 * 117269
5042631 - 5^3  =   5042631 - 125  =  5042506 = 2 * 7 * 17 * 21187
5042631 - 6^3  =   5042631 - 216  =  5042415 = 3 * 5 * 7 * 48023
5042631 - 7^3  =   5042631 - 343  =  5042288 = 2^4 * 29 * 10867
5042631 - 8^3  =   5042631 - 512  =  5042119 = 31 * 162649
5042631 - 9^3  =   5042631 - 729  =  5041902 = 2 * 3 * 31 * 27107
5042631 - 10^3  =   5042631 - 1000  =  5041631 = 7 * 19 * 37907
5042631 - 11^3  =   5042631 - 1331  =  5041300 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 11 * 4583
5042631 - 12^3  =   5042631 - 1728  =  5040903 = 3 * 7 * 240043
5042631 - 13^3  =   5042631 - 2197  =  5040434 = 2 * 7^2 * 19 * 2707
5042631 - 14^3  =   5042631 - 2744  =  5039887 = 31 * 162577
5042631 - 15^3  =   5042631 - 3375  =  5039256 = 2^3 * 3 * 19 * 43 * 257
5042631 - 16^3  =   5042631 - 4096  =  5038535 = 5 * 631 * 1597
5042631 - 17^3  =   5042631 - 4913  =  5037718 = 2 * 7 * 359837
5042631 - 18^3  =   5042631 - 5832  =  5036799 = 3 * 419 * 4007
5042631 - 19^3  =   5042631 - 6859  =  5035772 = 2^2 * 7 * 179849
5042631 - 20^3  =   5042631 - 8000  =  5034631 = 7 * 23 * 31271
5042631 - 21^3  =   5042631 - 9261  =  5033370 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 167779
5042631 - 22^3  =   5042631 - 10648  =  5031983 = 11 * 17 * 71 * 379
5042631 - 23^3  =   5042631 - 12167  =  5030464 = 2^6 * 83 * 947
5042631 - 24^3  =   5042631 - 13824  =  5028807 = 3 * 7 * 43 * 5569
5042631 - 25^3  =   5042631 - 15625  =  5027006 = 2 * 2513503
5042631 - 26^3  =   5042631 - 17576  =  5025055 = 5 * 7 * 143573
5042631 - 27^3  =   5042631 - 19683  =  5022948 = 2^2 * 3 * 7 * 59797
5042631 - 28^3  =   5042631 - 21952  =  5020679 = 1637 * 3067
5042631 - 29^3  =   5042631 - 24389  =  5018242 = 2 * 19 * 132059
5042631 - 30^3  =   5042631 - 27000  =  5015631 = 3 * 79 * 21163
5042631 - 31^3  =   5042631 - 29791  =  5012840 = 2^3 * 5 * 7 * 17903
5042631 - 32^3  =   5042631 - 32768  =  5009863 = 19 * 263677
5042631 - 33^3  =   5042631 - 35937  =  5006694 = 2 * 3 * 7 * 11 * 10837
5042631 - 34^3  =   5042631 - 39304  =  5003327 = 7 * 19 * 37619
5042631 - 35^3  =   5042631 - 42875  =  4999756 = 2^2 * 1249939
5042631 - 36^3  =   5042631 - 46656  =  4995975 = 3 * 5^2 * 29 * 2297
5042631 - 37^3  =   5042631 - 50653  =  4991978 = 2 * 107 * 23327
5042631 - 38^3  =   5042631 - 54872  =  4987759 = 7^2 * 137 * 743
5042631 - 39^3  =   5042631 - 59319  =  4983312 = 2^4 * 3 * 17 * 31 * 197
5042631 - 40^3  =   5042631 - 64000  =  4978631 = 7 * 31 * 22943
5042631 - 41^3  =   5042631 - 68921  =  4973710 = 2 * 5 * 7 * 41 * 1733
5042631 - 42^3  =   5042631 - 74088  =  4968543 = 3 * 499 * 3319
5042631 - 43^3  =   5042631 - 79507  =  4963124 = 2^2 * 23 * 73 * 739
5042631 - 44^3  =   5042631 - 85184  =  4957447 = 11 * 450677
5042631 - 45^3  =   5042631 - 91125  =  4951506 = 2 * 3 * 7 * 31 * 3803
5042631 - 46^3  =   5042631 - 97336  =  4945295 = 5 * 989059
5042631 - 47^3  =   5042631 - 103823  =  4938808 = 2^3 * 7^2 * 43 * 293
5042631 - 48^3  =   5042631 - 110592  =  4932039 = 3 * 7 * 19 * 47 * 263
5042631 - 49^3  =   5042631 - 117649  =  4924982 = 2 * 467 * 5273
5042631 - 50^3  =   5042631 - 125000  =  4917631 = 4917631
5042631 - 51^3  =   5042631 - 132651  =  4909980 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 19 * 59 * 73
5042631 - 52^3  =   5042631 - 140608  =  4902023 = 7 * 53 * 73 * 181
5042631 - 53^3  =   5042631 - 148877  =  4893754 = 2 * 19 * 89 * 1447
5042631 - 54^3  =   5042631 - 157464  =  4885167 = 3 * 7 * 353 * 659
5042631 - 55^3  =   5042631 - 166375  =  4876256 = 2^5 * 7 * 11 * 1979
5042631 - 56^3  =   5042631 - 175616  =  4867015 = 5 * 17 * 57259
5042631 - 57^3  =   5042631 - 185193  =  4857438 = 2 * 3 * 631 * 1283
5042631 - 58^3  =   5042631 - 195112  =  4847519 = 43 * 79 * 1427
5042631 - 59^3  =   5042631 - 205379  =  4837252 = 2^2 * 7 * 172759
5042631 - 60^3  =   5042631 - 216000  =  4826631 = 3 * 601 * 2677
5042631 - 61^3  =   5042631 - 226981  =  4815650 = 2 * 5^2 * 7 * 13759
5042631 - 62^3  =   5042631 - 238328  =  4804303 = 7^2 * 98047
5042631 - 63^3  =   5042631 - 250047  =  4792584 = 2^3 * 3 * 397 * 503
5042631 - 64^3  =   5042631 - 262144  =  4780487 = 4780487
5042631 - 65^3  =   5042631 - 274625  =  4768006 = 2 * 29 * 82207
5042631 - 66^3  =   5042631 - 287496  =  4755135 = 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 23 * 179
5042631 - 67^3  =   5042631 - 300763  =  4741868 = 2^2 * 19 * 43 * 1451
5042631 - 68^3  =   5042631 - 314432  =  4728199 = 7 * 675457
5042631 - 69^3  =   5042631 - 328509  =  4714122 = 2 * 3 * 7 * 112241
5042631 - 70^3  =   5042631 - 343000  =  4699631 = 19 * 31 * 79 * 101
5042631 - 71^3  =   5042631 - 357911  =  4684720 = 2^4 * 5 * 31 * 1889
5042631 - 72^3  =   5042631 - 373248  =  4669383 = 3 * 19 * 81919
5042631 - 73^3  =   5042631 - 389017  =  4653614 = 2 * 7 * 17 * 19553
5042631 - 74^3  =   5042631 - 405224  =  4637407 = 113 * 41039
5042631 - 75^3  =   5042631 - 421875  =  4620756 = 2^2 * 3 * 7 * 55009
5042631 - 76^3  =   5042631 - 438976  =  4603655 = 5 * 7 * 31 * 4243
5042631 - 77^3  =   5042631 - 456533  =  4586098 = 2 * 11 * 208459
5042631 - 78^3  =   5042631 - 474552  =  4568079 = 3 * 1522693
5042631 - 79^3  =   5042631 - 493039  =  4549592 = 2^3 * 568699
5042631 - 80^3  =   5042631 - 512000  =  4530631 = 7 * 617 * 1049
5042631 - 81^3  =   5042631 - 531441  =  4511190 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 150373
5042631 - 82^3  =   5042631 - 551368  =  4491263 = 7 * 41 * 15649
5042631 - 83^3  =   5042631 - 571787  =  4470844 = 2^2 * 7 * 159673
5042631 - 84^3  =   5042631 - 592704  =  4449927 = 3 * 1483309
5042631 - 85^3  =   5042631 - 614125  =  4428506 = 2 * 167 * 13259
5042631 - 86^3  =   5042631 - 636056  =  4406575 = 5^2 * 19 * 9277
5042631 - 87^3  =   5042631 - 658503  =  4384128 = 2^7 * 3 * 7^2 * 233
5042631 - 88^3  =   5042631 - 681472  =  4361159 = 11 * 211 * 1879
5042631 - 89^3  =   5042631 - 704969  =  4337662 = 2 * 7 * 19 * 23 * 709
5042631 - 90^3  =   5042631 - 729000  =  4313631 = 3 * 7 * 17 * 43 * 281
5042631 - 91^3  =   5042631 - 753571  =  4289060 = 2^2 * 5 * 19 * 11287
5042631 - 92^3  =   5042631 - 778688  =  4263943 = 1901 * 2243
5042631 - 93^3  =   5042631 - 804357  =  4238274 = 2 * 3 * 71 * 9949
5042631 - 94^3  =   5042631 - 830584  =  4212047 = 7 * 29 * 20749
5042631 - 95^3  =   5042631 - 857375  =  4185256 = 2^3 * 47 * 11131
5042631 - 96^3  =   5042631 - 884736  =  4157895 = 3 * 5 * 7^2 * 5657
5042631 - 97^3  =   5042631 - 912673  =  4129958 = 2 * 7 * 294997
5042631 - 98^3  =   5042631 - 941192  =  4101439 = 1523 * 2693
5042631 - 99^3  =   5042631 - 970299  =  4072332 = 2^2 * 3 * 11 * 30851
5042631 - 100^3  =   5042631 - 1000000  =  4042631 = 4042631
5042631 - 101^3  =   5042631 - 1030301  =  4012330 = 2 * 5 * 7 * 31 * 43^2
5042631 - 102^3  =   5042631 - 1061208  =  3981423 = 3 * 31^2 * 1381
5042631 - 103^3  =   5042631 - 1092727  =  3949904 = 2^4 * 7 * 35267
5042631 - 104^3  =   5042631 - 1124864  =  3917767 = 7 * 359 * 1559
5042631 - 105^3  =   5042631 - 1157625  =  3885006 = 2 * 3 * 19 * 53 * 643
5042631 - 106^3  =   5042631 - 1191016  =  3851615 = 5 * 83 * 9281
5042631 - 107^3  =   5042631 - 1225043  =  3817588 = 2^2 * 17 * 31 * 1811
5042631 - 108^3  =   5042631 - 1259712  =  3782919 = 3 * 7 * 19^2 * 499
5042631 - 109^3  =   5042631 - 1295029  =  3747602 = 2 * 79 * 23719
5042631 - 110^3  =   5042631 - 1331000  =  3711631 = 7 * 11 * 19 * 43 * 59
5042631 - 111^3  =   5042631 - 1367631  =  3675000 = 2^3 * 3 * 5^5 * 7^2
5042631 - 112^3  =   5042631 - 1404928  =  3637703 = 23 * 158161
5042631 - 113^3  =   5042631 - 1442897  =  3599734 = 2 * 1799867
5042631 - 114^3  =   5042631 - 1481544  =  3561087 = 3 * 223 * 5323
5042631 - 115^3  =   5042631 - 1520875  =  3521756 = 2^2 * 7 * 125777
5042631 - 116^3  =   5042631 - 1560896  =  3481735 = 5 * 73 * 9539
5042631 - 117^3  =   5042631 - 1601613  =  3441018 = 2 * 3 * 7 * 81929
5042631 - 118^3  =   5042631 - 1643032  =  3399599 = 7 * 485657
5042631 - 119^3  =   5042631 - 1685159  =  3357472 = 2^5 * 239 * 439
5042631 - 120^3  =   5042631 - 1728000  =  3314631 = 3 * 1104877
5042631 - 121^3  =   5042631 - 1771561  =  3271070 = 2 * 5 * 11 * 131 * 227
5042631 - 122^3  =   5042631 - 1815848  =  3226783 = 7 * 460969
5042631 - 123^3  =   5042631 - 1860867  =  3181764 = 2^2 * 3 * 29 * 41 * 223
5042631 - 124^3  =   5042631 - 1906624  =  3136007 = 7 * 17 * 19^2 * 73
5042631 - 125^3  =   5042631 - 1953125  =  3089506 = 2 * 7 * 73 * 3023
5042631 - 126^3  =   5042631 - 2000376  =  3042255 = 3 * 5 * 202817
5042631 - 127^3  =   5042631 - 2048383  =  2994248 = 2^3 * 19 * 19699
5042631 - 128^3  =   5042631 - 2097152  =  2945479 = 2945479
5042631 - 129^3  =   5042631 - 2146689  =  2895942 = 2 * 3 * 7 * 19^2 * 191
5042631 - 130^3  =   5042631 - 2197000  =  2845631 = 2845631
5042631 - 131^3  =   5042631 - 2248091  =  2794540 = 2^2 * 5 * 7 * 19961
5042631 - 132^3  =   5042631 - 2299968  =  2742663 = 3 * 7 * 11 * 31 * 383
5042631 - 133^3  =   5042631 - 2352637  =  2689994 = 2 * 31 * 43 * 1009
5042631 - 134^3  =   5042631 - 2406104  =  2636527 = 2636527
5042631 - 135^3  =   5042631 - 2460375  =  2582256 = 2^4 * 3 * 23 * 2339
5042631 - 136^3  =   5042631 - 2515456  =  2527175 = 5^2 * 7^2 * 2063
5042631 - 137^3  =   5042631 - 2571353  =  2471278 = 2 * 79 * 15641
5042631 - 138^3  =   5042631 - 2628072  =  2414559 = 3 * 7 * 31 * 3709
5042631 - 139^3  =   5042631 - 2685619  =  2357012 = 2^2 * 7 * 84179
5042631 - 140^3  =   5042631 - 2744000  =  2298631 = 2298631
5042631 - 141^3  =   5042631 - 2803221  =  2239410 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 17 * 4391
5042631 - 142^3  =   5042631 - 2863288  =  2179343 = 47 * 89 * 521
5042631 - 143^3  =   5042631 - 2924207  =  2118424 = 2^3 * 7 * 11 * 19 * 181
5042631 - 144^3  =   5042631 - 2985984  =  2056647 = 3 * 43 * 107 * 149
5042631 - 145^3  =   5042631 - 3048625  =  1994006 = 2 * 7^2 * 20347
5042631 - 146^3  =   5042631 - 3112136  =  1930495 = 5 * 7 * 19 * 2903
5042631 - 147^3  =   5042631 - 3176523  =  1866108 = 2^2 * 3 * 155509
5042631 - 148^3  =   5042631 - 3241792  =  1800839 = 19 * 94781
5042631 - 149^3  =   5042631 - 3307949  =  1734682 = 2 * 79 * 10979
5042631 - 150^3  =   5042631 - 3375000  =  1667631 = 3 * 7 * 79411
5042631 - 151^3  =   5042631 - 3442951  =  1599680 = 2^6 * 5 * 4999
5042631 - 152^3  =   5042631 - 3511808  =  1530823 = 7 * 29 * 7541
5042631 - 153^3  =   5042631 - 3581577  =  1461054 = 2 * 3 * 7 * 43 * 809
5042631 - 154^3  =   5042631 - 3652264  =  1390367 = 11 * 126397
5042631 - 155^3  =   5042631 - 3723875  =  1318756 = 2^2 * 439 * 751
5042631 - 156^3  =   5042631 - 3796416  =  1246215 = 3 * 5 * 251 * 331
5042631 - 157^3  =   5042631 - 3869893  =  1172738 = 2 * 7 * 211 * 397
5042631 - 158^3  =   5042631 - 3944312  =  1098319 = 17 * 23 * 53^2
5042631 - 159^3  =   5042631 - 4019679  =  1022952 = 2^3 * 3 * 7 * 6089
5042631 - 160^3  =   5042631 - 4096000  =  946631 = 7^2 * 19319
5042631 - 161^3  =   5042631 - 4173281  =  869350 = 2 * 5^2 * 17387
5042631 - 162^3  =   5042631 - 4251528  =  791103 = 3 * 19 * 13879
5042631 - 163^3  =   5042631 - 4330747  =  711884 = 2^2 * 31 * 5741
5042631 - 164^3  =   5042631 - 4410944  =  631687 = 7 * 31 * 41 * 71
5042631 - 165^3  =   5042631 - 4492125  =  550506 = 2 * 3 * 11 * 19 * 439
5042631 - 166^3  =   5042631 - 4574296  =  468335 = 5 * 7 * 13381
5042631 - 167^3  =   5042631 - 4657463  =  385168 = 2^4 * 7 * 19 * 181
5042631 - 168^3  =   5042631 - 4741632  =  300999 = 3 * 100333
5042631 - 169^3  =   5042631 - 4826809  =  215822 = 2 * 31 * 59^2
5042631 - 170^3  =   5042631 - 4913000  =  129631 = 129631
5042631 - 171^3  =   5042631 - 5000211  =  42420 = 2^2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 101
5042631 - 172^3  =   5042631 - 5088448  =  -45817 =  -1 * 45817
```

---

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[image]
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: If I understand correctly the only way $1013$ can be written as a sum of two squares is $22^2+23^2$ (up to permutation and signs), neither of which corresponds to $b=22,23$ being a multiple of $5$.

Comment: @anon, I put in the one they want in purple.

Comment: What method did you use to find the purple answer? Was it a matter of testing a bunch of values of 'a' to find it?

Comment: @user106331, yes, I do not see any elegant method, and the bit about 5 turned out to require all solutions before the useful one appeared. So: if we can factor a positive integer, we can decide whether it is the sum of two squares and find all possible ways of writing it as such.

Comment: @Will Jagy. I am very very bad in arithmetics. Just by curiosity, to what corresponds 5,042,631 ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici calculated expression for 5042631, edited into answer, along with

Comment: The monthly problem you link to is very nice! I can only stare at those identities with awe...

Comment: @Prism, it is suspected that $x^2 + y^2 - z^5$ and $x^2 + y^2 - z^7$ and $x^2 + y^2 - z^q$ for odd prime $q$ are likewise universal, but I found no identities. Meanwhile, for odd composite exponent, we find $$ x^2 + y^2 - z^9 \neq 216 p^3  $$ for prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4.$ Similar behavior for   $x^2 + y^2 - z^{15}$ or  $x^2 + y^2 - z^{35}$ or  $x^2 + y^2 - z^{91}$ as $91 = 7 \cdot 13.$

Comment: @WillJagy: Thanks for further information. That's a striking conjecture! When I am bored in bus, I shall play with $x^2+y^2-z^5$. :)